# how to install latest version of prometheus/promtool in ubuntu?

Tags: grafana, prometheus, rules, prometheus-alertmanager

I downloaded my prometheus version is 2.3.2

```
wget https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/download/v2.3.2/prometheus-2.3.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

untared and prometheus already running as service.

I want to verify my Prometheus alert manager rule using promtool.
created one rule from below blog.

https://petargitnik.github.io/blog/2018/01/04/how-to-write-rules-for-prometheus

when I run the 
promtool check rules /etc/prometheus/prometheus.rules.yml

it says, Promtheus not installed, so installed again using 
apt get prometheus

but this is installed older verion of promtool, here is version details:

```
    root@UTVA-kafka-msg-size-2mb-02509:/home/ubuntu# promtool version
prometheus, version 0.16.2+ds (branch: debian/sid, revision: 0.16.2+ds-1ubuntu1)

build user:       pkg-go-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
  build date:       20160408-04:15:29
  go version:       go1.6
```

Prometheus version 2 using yml file for rules, older usign some different one, so my promtool check-rules  is failing.

Can anyone suggest how to upgrade latest promtool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `go` to install the latest/desired version directly from github. Make sure you have *go* setup. For convenience also add GOPATH to your PATH, e.g. for ZSH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

And then you can install it using `go get`:

```
GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/prometheus/prometheus/cmd/promtool
```

Now that you have GOPATH in your PATH you can simply call it from your shell:

```
➜  ~ promtool --version
promtool, version  (branch: , revision: )
 build user:
 build date:
 go version:       go1.12.7
```

**EDIT:**

Make sure you prepend `GO111MODULE=on` to the `go` command as [the `vendor` directory has been removed](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/8586#issuecomment-796796881)

Comment: `go get` with the https scheme don't work. Correct is `go get github.com/prometheus/prometheus/cmd/promtool`

Comment: Since 1.17 `go get` does not work anymore for installing commands. However I could not install it using `go install` neither. It complains about the go.mod file containing replace directives. Any idea? https://go.dev/doc/go-get-install-deprecation

Answer (score 8):

Updated answer:

Starting with Go >= 1.16 you should no longer use `go get` to globally install outside a specific project.

Usually you would like to use `go install`:

```bash
# This won't work
go install github.com/prometheus/prometheus/cmd/promtool@latest
```

But promtool is not the main project on github.com/prometheus/prometheus, so that will not work.

You can download and uncompress the latest promtool binary on the fly to the current directory using:

```bash
VERSION=$(curl -Ls https://api.github.com/repos/prometheus/prometheus/releases/latest | jq ".tag_name" | xargs | cut -c2-)
wget -qO- "https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/download/v${VERSION}/prometheus-$VERSION.linux-amd64.tar.gz" \
  | tar xvzf - "prometheus-$VERSION.linux-amd64"/promtool --strip-components=1
```

Take into consideration that calls to `api.github.com` are IP throttle if you make many in a short time.

If you want to install [Alertmanager CLI](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager#amtool) `amtool`, it's simpler:

```
# This takes 450Mb, look for the alternative
go install github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/cmd/amtool@latest
```

But that will take 450Mb from your disk. To use only 25Mb aprox, instead:

```bash
VERSION=$(curl -Ls https://api.github.com/repos/prometheus/alertmanager/releases/latest | jq ".tag_name" | xargs | cut -c2-)
wget -qO- "https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/releases/download/v${VERSION}/alertmanager-$VERSION.linux-amd64.tar.gz" \
  | tar xvzf - "alertmanager-$VERSION.linux-amd64"/amtool --strip-components=1
```

Lastly, if you are interested in linting rules, take a look at [pint](https://github.com/cloudflare/pint) from CloudFlare (read [this blog post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/monitoring-our-monitoring/)):

```bash
VERSION=$(curl -Ls https://api.github.com/repos/cloudflare/pint/releases/latest | jq ".tag_name" | xargs | cut -c2-)
wget -qO- "https://github.com/cloudflare/pint/releases/download/v${VERSION}/pint-$VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.gz" \
  | tar xvzf - pint-linux-amd64 && mv pint-linux-amd64 pint
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to include the branch:

```
GO111MODULE=on go get -v github.com/prometheus/prometheus/cmd/promtool@master
```